# In spring framework if i use annotations instead of XML configuration do i need to initialize the spring container in a separate class?

Tags: spring, frameworks

In spring framework if i use annotations instead of XML configuration do i need to initialize the spring container in a separate class like below.

class AppContextProj{

```
    public static void main(String [] args){
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(YourConfiguration1.class, YourConfiguration2.class, ...);
```

It accepts `@Configuration`-annotated classes in constructor.

Or

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.company.basepackage1", "com.company.basepackage2", ...);
```

which will automatically scan for `@Configuration`- and `@Component`-annotated classes (including `@Service`, `@Repository` and so on) in the specified packages and pick them up.

Comment: so i need to initialize the spring container when i use annotations

Comment: There has to be some bootstrap initialization. If this is a standalone application (your example looks like it is), then yes, you have to do it explicitly.